# How to troubleshoot 100% CPU usage issue with a TCP server?

Tags: c#, .net, cpu-usage, tcpserver

I've made a TCP server in C# (as a Windows service) that is based largely on the sample Asynchronous Server Socket code in MSDN. However after about a couple of days in operation, it starts using 100% of the CPU on the dev machine and stays there until I stop and restart the service. The weird thing is it still works correctly, even when the service hits max CPU usage, so functionality is never an issue.

I asked about it on StackOverflow here  - http://goo.gl/XB2C5 but I guess there were no obvious issues with the code that I had pasted. I've monitored the number of threads that the program uses and it always is between 14-17, so I don't think that's an issue.

Now I'm a bit stuck and don't know how to troubleshoot this problem. Are there any tools I could be using or more diagnostic code that I could add to find out what's causing the CPU usage to spike? I just need some guidance on how to further investigate the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One of the tools is Process Monitor. If you manage to configure symbols correctly, it can give quite a lot of interesting information about what is going on on your program stack. If you never have used Process Monitor before, there's series of video explaining how to use it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963887.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Thread.Sleep() to the end of the following loop, does that stop the 100% cpu?

```
 while (true)
 {
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
    allDone.Reset();                    

    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
    allDone.WaitOne();

    Thread.Sleep() //This makes the thread wait for its next timeslice
    //Thread.Yield()  //This makes the thread wait on another change to run from the OS wich might be much faster then Thread.Sleep(). 
 }
```

Comment: I'll certainly try that. So make the main thread sleep immediately after it receives the Set event from the other thread, so that there is a delay before the the flag is Reset?

Comment: Other options are seriously debugging the code by running it in a profiler. ANTS profiler has a free trails and some VS.net versions have a profiler build-in. Another options is simply pressing the pause button when debugging to find where the current execution pointer is pointing.